# Windows Explorer - restore list of favorites from previous OS version

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, data-recovery

I broke my Windows 10 installation (but not my files) by overclocking. I am moving the files to a Windows 7 installation, but I cannot figure out how to transfer the contents of Explorer's Favorites, or Quick Access as it is in Windows 10. I'd like to either restore those entries to the Windows 7 Favorites list, or retrieve the paths that they pointed to.

[image]

Comment: You will have to provide a translation into English.  I don't know what anything in that screenshot says, and per the **community guidelines**, questions should be in English.

Comment: Question is in English, screenshot not, I know it may be aginst rules, but there is tutorial: open any Explorer.exe window in Win7 and newer, check pannel on left, looks pretty same but in your system language. I have no access to Windows in Englsih right now, sorry.

Comment: You could provide a manual English translation to the interface though.

Comment: Ok, in that red Square: Favourites(Last opened, Desktop, Downloads); Under red square: Libraries(Documents, Music, Pictures)

Answer (score 1):

The Quick access Pinned items are kept in a **.automaticDestinations-ms** file which is not plain text, where as "Favorites" in previous Windows OS were stored in %userprofile%\Links as normal shortcuts. I'm afraid the Quick access shortcuts can't be transferred directly to Favorites.